# Generating URL using USGS Site-Test-Tool to add as Layer in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, usgs, url, hydrography

I am trying to use http://waterservices.usgs.gov/rest/Site-Test-Tool.html to generate a Rest URL to add as a Layer in ArcGIS Online.

I generated url (http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/site/?format=ge&stateCd=va&outputDataTypeCd=iv) using USGS Site Web Service URL Generation Tool but unable to add layer in ArcGIS Online using this rest url.